# Web scraping an "onclick" object table on a website with python

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape the data for this link: [page](http://www.ibex.bg/bg/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0/%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8/%D1%82%D1%8A%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80/).

If you click the up arrow you will notice the highlighted days in the month sections. Clicking on a highlighted day, a table with initiated tenders for that day will appear. All I need to do is get the data in each table for each highlighted day in the calendar. There might be one or more tenders (up to max of 7) per day.

[Table appears on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dQvR.png)

I have done some web scraping with bs4, however I think that this is a job for selenium (please, correct me if I am wrong) with which I am not very familiar.

So far, I have managed to find the arrow element by XPATH to navigate around the calendar and show me more months. After that I try clicking on a random day (in below code I clicked on 30.03.2020) upon which an html object called: "tenders-table cloned" appears in the html on inspect. The object name stays the same no matter what day you click on.

I am pretty stuck now, have tried to select by iterate and/or print what is inside that object table, it either says that ***object is not iterable*** or is ***None***.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\<name>\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("http://www.ibex.bg/bg/данни-за-пазара/централизиран-пазар-за-двустранни-договори/търговски-календар/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/i""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]""").click()
```

Please advice how I can proceed to extract the data from the table pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i see there's no reason to use `selenium` for such case as it's will slow down your task.

The website is loaded with `JavaScript` event which render it's data dynamically once the page loads.

`requests` library will not be able to render `JavaScript` on the fly. so you can use `selenium` or `requests_html`. and indeed there's a lot of modules which can do that.

Now, we do have another option on the table, to track from where the data is rendered. I were able to locate the [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request which is used to retrieve the data from the `back-end` `API` and render it to the users side.

> You can get the `XHR` request by open [Developer-Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and check `XHR/JS` requests made depending of the type of call such as `fetch`

```py
import requests
import json

data = {
    'from': '2020-1-01',
    'to': '2020-3-01'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
    print(json.dumps(r, indent=4)) # to see it in nice format.
    print(r.keys())


main("http://www.ibex.bg/ajax/tenders_ajax.php")
```

Because am just a lazy coder: I will do it in this way:

```py
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import ast
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'from': '2020-1-01',
    'to': '2020-3-01'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
    matches = set(re.findall(r"tender_date': '([^']*)'", str(r)))
    sort = (sorted(matches, key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(k, '%d.%m.%Y')))
    print(f"Available Dates: {sort}")
    opa = re.findall(r"({\'id.*?})", str(r))
    convert = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in opa]
    df = pd.DataFrame(convert)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("http://www.ibex.bg/ajax/tenders_ajax.php")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/50538fb8f1d7f188ce95e668228e9698/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate! That is perfectly straight to the point solution! I was also looking into the XHR in the dev tools, however I found myself a little confused. Now it is much more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @sc-coder you welcome, you know how to handle the rest well :)?

Comment: Yep, I think I will handle it. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @sc-coder check updated answer :P just for a record

Comment: nice one! Pretty elegant! Laziness all the way! :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try below solution

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  


elemnt=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='tenders']/div[@class='form-group']/div[1]/div[1]//i")))
    elemnt.click()
    elemnt1=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group']//div[1]//div[3]//table[1]//tbody[1]//tr[6]//td[1]")))
    elemnt1.click()
    lists=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='tenders-table cloned']")))
    for element in lists:
         print element.text
```

Comment: Hey, Dipak. Thanks for the solution. Please note that my code above also finds the elements and clicks on them in order for the table to come up. My problem is how can I proceed to gather the data in each table that appears upon clicking on the highlighted days. I have also tried your solution and it returns a blank page.

Comment: Thanks! That works fine and extracts a list for a single highlighted day in the calendar.

Comment: Hi Dipak, please note that αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη answer is much better and straight to the point. My need was to identify and extract the data in each of the highlighted days, not just one and his solution is much faster. Thank you again for your solution. I am afraid I cannot upvote your answers since my account is still new. Will try later though.