# Need help web scraping table with beautifulsoup and selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am working on trying to webscrape https://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/surveymost?bls and was able to figure out how to webcrawl through clicks to get to a table.

The selection that I am practicing on is after you select the checkbox associated with " Employment Cost Index (ECI) Civilian (Unadjusted) - CIU1010000000000A" under Compensation and then select "Retrieve data".

Once those two are processed a table shows. This is the table I am trying to scrape.

Below is the code that I have as of right now.

Note that you have to put your own path for your browser driver where I have put < browser driver >.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/surveymost?bls"
ChromeSource = r"<browser driver>"

# Open up a Chrome browser and navigate to web page.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless') # will run without opening browser.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeSource, chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @value = 'CIU1010000000000A']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='Submit' and @value = 'Retrieve data']").click()

i = 2

def myTEST(i):
    xpath = '//*[@id="col' + str(i) + '"]'
    TEST = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

    num_page_items = len(TEST)
    for i in range(num_page_items):
        print(TEST[i].text)
myTEST(i)

# Clean up (close browser once completed task).
driver.close()
```

Right now this only is looking at the headers. I would like to also get the table content as well.

If I make i = 0, it produces "Year". i = 1, it produces "Period". But if I select i = 2 I get two  variables which have the same col2 id for "Estimated Value" and "Standard Error".

I tried to think of a way to work around this and can't seem to get anything that I have researched to work.

In essence, it would be better to start at the point where I am done clicking and am at the table of interest and then look at the xpath of the header  and pull in the text for all of the sub 's.

```
<tr> == $0
  <th id="col0"> Year </th>
  <th id="col1"> Period </th>
  <th id="col2">Estimated Value</th>
  <th id="col2">Standard Error</th>
<tr>
```

I am not sure how to do that. I also tried to loop through the {i} but obviously sharing  with two header text causes an issue.

Once I am able to get the header, I want to get the contents. I could you some insight on if I am on the right path, overthinking it or if there is a simpler way to do all of this. I am learning and this is my first attempt using the selenium library for clicks. I just want to get it to work so I can try it again on a different table and make it as automate or reusable (with tweaking) as possible.

Comment: Scrapping or scraping?

Comment: [Edited] Scraping*

Thanks for catching that, through a spelling mistake is not really the point of what I am asking for help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you don't need `selenium`, You can just track the `POST` `Form data`, and apply the same within your `POST` request.

Then you can load the table using `Pandas` easily.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "series_id": "CIU1010000000000A",
    "survey": "bls"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)
    df = pd.read_html(r.content)[1]
    print(df)


main("https://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/surveymost")
```

Explanation:

- open the [site](https://data.bls.gov/cgi-bin/surveymost?bls).
- Select `Employment Cost Index (ECI) Civilian (Unadjusted) - CIU1010000000000A`
- Now you have to open your browser [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and navigate to `Network Monitor` section. *etc* Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> ( <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> on a Mac).
- Now you will found a `POST` request done.

  [image]
- Navigate to `Params` tab.

  [image]
- Now you can make the `POST` request. and since the `Table` is presented within the `HTML` source and it's not loaded via `JavaScript`, so you can parse it within `bs4` or read it in nice format using [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Note: You can read the table as long as it's not loaded via `JavaScript`. otherwise you can try to track the `XHR` request (Check previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990295/7658985)) or you can use `selenium` or `requests_html` to render `JS` since `requests` is an `HTTP` library which can't render it for you.

Comment: Wow!!! Not only did that work, but it is so dynamic that it works with the other tables as well! I was definitely overthinking it but then again, I don't fully understand how this works. I will need to digest it some more to figure that part out but thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewHicks you welcome, let me know in case if you found anything unclear so i can explain

Comment: Yeah...do you know of any "literature" that might cover the concept of what you did here? My background is in analytics (python, r and sql) and not html. Is the information in the data = {} different for every website? Can I use this on let's say yahoo finance or any other page that has a table? I would assume that some tweaks would be needed (aside from the url and the data variables like you put in series_id and survey. Thanks again. I definitely want to learn this.

Comment: @AndrewHicks well let me explain that within the answer. hold on

Comment: So a follow-up. First off, it looks like this method is not appropriate for all websites which is alright for now. Second, I want to tweak the code that that it doesn't just go from 2010-2020, but rather 1939-2020. On the website this requires selecting 1939 from the dropping on the top and then selecting "go".

I tried going about it your way, but it only errors out. Any ideas?

data = "from_year" : "1939", & "to_year" : "2020".

Also, so I take it that the params field exist in FireFox. Do you know if there is something similar in Chrome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212887/discussion-between--c-and-andrew-hicks).