# Extract unix timestamp from <tag datetime="unix-timestamp">

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

Im trying to get multiple unix timestamp from a html source code that I can convert to yyyy-mm-dd and then later pass it to google calendar to make events. I can't seem to get the unix timestamp from `<tag datetime="">`. The tag before this one is `<div class="matchlist__match__column--details">`

`soup.find_all('time')` shows me that everything I need is there and I can get the first unix timestamp with `soup.find('time', {'datetime': True})['datetime']`. I can also use `get_text()`, but the string is written `d. month - hh:mm`, which is no good if I want it in google calendar.

I had some promising leads but i keep getting error messages and my search results have not been fruitful or maybe im missing something obvious. I've teached myself from scratch for two months and im still a beginner any input on my methods are welcome.

```
soup.find_all('time', datetime = True)['datetime']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

```
# The website im collecting data from will announce
# the game dates for next season soon and i
# want to help a friend of mine who manages one
# of the team as a way to teach myself python.

# Note that the webpage here is a placeholder
# and the dates are in the past.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/folder/chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")                                    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)             
driver.get("https://www.telialigaen.no/rl/resultater?division=6221&season=6091") 

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

homeTeam = []
for el in soup.find_all('strong', attrs={'class': 'mr-2'}):
    homeTeam.append(el.get_text())

awayTeam = []
for el in soup.find_all('strong', attrs={'class': 'ml-2'}):
    awayTeam.append(el.get_text())

date = []
# i dunno

# The goal is to have all teams and dates in nice
# separate lists. 
# From here I will pick myTeam and create google
# calendar events the day they are playing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    "referrer": "https://www.telialigaen.no/rl/resultater?division=6221&season=6091"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Home Team", "Date", "Away Team"])
        for data in r:
            writer.writerow([data['homeTeam']['name'],
                             data['startTime'], data['awayTeam']['name']])


main("https://www.telialigaen.no/api/matches?division=6221&game=rl&limit=100&offset=0&order=roundNumber&season=6091&status=finished")
```

Output:

```
Home Team,Date,Away Team
PuttaGutta,2019-11-03 19:00:00,Domino Esport
UnTouchables,2019-11-03 19:00:00,Electric Taco
For En Tragedie,2019-10-31 20:00:00,Smerte
UnTouchables,2019-10-24 21:00:00,Domino Esport
Electric Taco,2019-10-24 19:00:00,Smerte
For En Tragedie,2019-10-24 19:00:00,Team SYRE
Smerte,2019-10-17 20:00:00,Domino Esport
PuttaGutta,2019-10-17 20:00:00,Ultra Handicap
Electric Taco,2019-10-15 19:00:00,Team SYRE
UnTouchables,2019-10-17 19:00:00,PuttaGutta
Domino Esport,2019-10-17 19:00:00,Team SYRE
Ultra Handicap,2019-10-17 19:00:00,For En Tragedie
UnTouchables,2019-09-30 19:30:00,Ultra Handicap
Electric Taco,2019-09-27 20:00:00,For En Tragedie
Smerte,2019-09-26 19:00:00,PuttaGutta
Team SYRE,2019-09-20 19:00:00,PuttaGutta
Smerte,2019-09-19 20:00:00,UnTouchables
Domino Esport,2019-09-19 19:00:00,For En Tragedie
Ultra Handicap,2019-09-19 18:00:00,Electric Taco
Smerte,2019-09-15 21:00:00,Ultra Handicap
Team SYRE,2019-09-13 18:30:00,UnTouchables
Domino Esport,2019-09-11 19:00:00,Electric Taco
PuttaGutta,2019-09-09 21:00:00,For En Tragedie
Team SYRE,2019-09-05 19:00:00,Smerte
Ultra Handicap,2019-09-05 19:00:00,Domino Esport
PuttaGutta,2019-08-29 21:00:00,Electric Taco
For En Tragedie,2019-08-29 19:00:00,UnTouchables
Team SYRE,2019-08-29 19:00:00,Ultra Handicap
```

Comment: Thank you! That is much appreciated. Wish you a nice weekend.

Comment: If I can ask you a follow up: How do I get the docs for this API the site is using? I would like to extrace one teamName spesific, but can't figure it out.

Comment: @AndletYo you are dealing with `JSON` dict so you can just use `print(data.keys())` to pickup what you looking for it. also check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515665/7658985)