# Trying to get data from JavaScript website

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
import pandas 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
time = []
ticker = []
name = []

URL = 'https://stockbeep.com/52-week-high-stock-screener'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
odd_rows = soup.find_all('tr', {'class':'odd'})
even_rows = soup.find_all('tr', {'class':'even'})

print(odd_rows)
print(even_rows)
```

the site is updating every 5 sec. It seems the problem is that  the (tbody) that contains the data of the table is not grabbed in soup and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        params = {
            "hash": soup.find('table', {'data-hash': True})['data-hash'],
            "country": "us",
            "time-zone": "-120",
            "sort-column": "position",
            "sort-order": "desc",
            # "_": "1617683270138"
        }
        r = req.get(
            'https://stockbeep.com/table-data/52-week-high-stock-screener', params=params)
        df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data'])
        df.drop(['xindex', 'sscode', 'ssarrow',
                'cellClasses'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv('Data.csv', index=False)


main('https://stockbeep.com/52-week-high-stock-screener')
```

Output:

```
   sstime                 ssname    sslast    sshigh  ... ssrvol    ytd  sscap position
0   15:36            Avis Budget     75.00     76.49  ...    3.1  101.0  5.18B  New ATH       
1   18:31                    KLA    355.08    359.69  ...    4.9   37.1  53.5B  New ATH       
2   19:22               Alphabet  2,218.96  2,228.99  ...    7.4   26.6  1.44T  New ATH       
3   18:45                    CSX     98.57     98.85  ...    3.5    8.6  73.9B  New ATH       
4   20:29                 Target    205.35    205.80  ...    3.9   16.3   100B  New ATH       
..    ...                    ...       ...       ...  ...    ...    ...    ...      ...       
95  16:23          Verizon Comms     58.87     59.13  ...    4.3    0.2   241B  3M high       
96  20:09         Dollar General    207.78    208.07  ...    4.3   -1.1  48.4B  3M high       
97  17:04                 Exelon     44.48     44.74  ...    4.9    5.3  42.9B  3M high       
98  18:48               NiSource     24.43     24.52  ...    4.0    6.4  9.43B  3M high       
99  15:35  United Parcel Service    171.95    173.04  ...    3.7    2.1   148B  3M high       

[100 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you sir. I could never figure this, not in a million years. 
specially the params part

Comment: @kokod you welcome. if my answer helps you. please accept it. also you can figure the params by yourself by following my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515665/7658985)