# Python Beautiful Webscraping Simulate Click to Scrape All Pages

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup

I ran into an interesting issue while trying to scrape http://www.o-review.com/database_filter_model.php?table_name=glasses&tag= containing 42 pages of data. I was able to successfully scrape the first page of information, but while trying to scrape all pages I found that the URL remains unchanged, and changing the page uses a button at the bottom of the website.

The html code in the inspector reads:

```
    <div onclick="filter_page('1')" class="filter_nav_button round5" 
    style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="/images/icon_arrow_next.svg"></div>
```

I'm very new at scraping and python but was told I need to simulate a "click" in the javascript which I have absolutely no idea how to do, and wasn't sure if it could be hard-coded. My weak attempt to try something so far:

```
    response = get('http://www.o-review.com/database_filter_model.php? 
    table_name=glasses&tag=')
    soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)

    for page in range(1, 42):
        pages = soup.find('div', onclick_ = 'filter_page()')
```

Hopefully, someone has solved this issue in the past. Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Here is the code I'm trying to add:

```
    ## Find All Frame models
    for find_frames in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'round5 
    grid_model'):
        # Each iteration grabs child text and prints it
        all_models = find_frames.text
        print(all_models)
```

This would be added where the comment was to add code! Thanks!

Comment: you aren't looping over the pages! you just loop over the `range`! you've to make a request for each page using the page num!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is made via `POST` request where you can check my [previous-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515665/7658985) in order to know how to get the actual `API`

Also `html.parser` or `lxml` is the not a part of your issue.

The reason why i used `lxml` because it's more fast than `html.parser` according to [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for page in range(1, 44):
            print("[*] - Extracting Page# {}".format(page))
            data = {
                "table_name": "glasses",
                "family": "",
                "page": "{}".format(page),
                "sort": "",
                "display": "list",
            }
            r = req.post(url, data=data)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            pp([x.text for x in soup.select(
                '.text-clip') if x.get_text(strip=True)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('http://www.o-review.com/ajax/database_filter_model.php')
```

Comment: @The_Bandit Kindly [edit] your post and highlight the data which you would like to extract.

Comment: I have edited my code with what I'm trying to add. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a confused with why my code was wrong... Also, I noticed you used lxml while I was using html.parser. Hopefully you can clarify! Thanks for the info!

Comment: @SIM Well, Regarding the format string, yes i mistyped it as i made multiple edits. regarding `from pprint import pp` <-- that's a valid import, try it in your end. finally the code works well. try it on your end. regarding the range it's correct as the first page is `1` and last page is `43`

Comment: I was getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'pp' from 'pprint'`, so I thought to inform you. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SIM https://i.imgur.com/AgHGpjP.png, you welcome. Kindly confirm for me your Python version ? as we already got `pprint` updated since 3.8. [check](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pp)

Comment: It's 3.7.0 here.

Comment: @SIM Make sense

Answer (score 0):

I saw the answer to this question and your comment. The reason αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη's code works is because it sends request to the actual ajax api the sit is getting data from. You could easily use your browser's developer tools to track it down. It's not because of lxml or whatever, you just had to find the right source ;)

And of course αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη should have explained some parts in his answer to clarify everything for you.