# BeautifulSoup can't properly find element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am looking at this website

https://shopee.sg/search?keyword=cosmetics

and when I search for xpath:

```
//div[@class="PFM7lj"]
```

It initially only finds 15 elements until I look at each item/scroll down to the end.
Then when I search it again, it shows 60 elements found

What do I need to do here?

Additionally when I call the item through BeautifulSoup I get a very different output like this:
[image: 15th Item]

but when I call the 16th item (results[15]), it shows:
[image: 15th element]

My code so far looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=options)

url = "https://shopee.sg/search?keyword=cosmetics"
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-sqe': 'item'})

print(results[14])
print(results[15])
```

Comment: modern pages use JavaScript to add element (they add when you scroll page - it is so called `"lazy loading"` to display page faster) but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: @furas but shouldn't it still work if I used headless chrome driver? it's still is giving me the same result

Comment: do you use `headless chrome driver`? I don't see it in code. Better show minimal working code which we could copy and run. Did you scroll page using `headless chrome driver`? Some server may also detect driver and block it.

Comment: @furas I mean there's literally nothing much to it but I did include it just in case you wanted to run it yourself :)

Comment: you have to scroll page before you get `driver.page_source` - `selenium` has some method to move to some element from end of page, or you may need to use JavaScript to scroll it. You should find few questions on Stackoverflow which show it.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests


def main(url):
    params = {
        "by": "relevancy",
        "keyword": "cosmetics",
        "limit": "100",  # maximum is 100 per page
        "newest": "0",  # you can loop from here 0, 100, 200 and so on
        "order": "desc",
        "page_type": "search",
        "scenario": "PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH",
        "version": "2"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    # print(f"Total Count: {r.json()['total_count']}") # can be used as a logic for loop
    for i in r.json()['items']:
        print(i['item_basic']['name'])


main('https://shopee.sg/api/v4/search/search_items')
```

Comment: care to do some explanation...?

Comment: @DHK [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515665/7658985) my previous answer which will learn you how to track an XHR request.

Comment: mind if I ask how I would loop this so I can get the data for the next page?

Comment: thanks, I think I got most of what I need from your answer and the previous answer on another post, but I can't seem to find the URL/link for each item? I can see that there are the names, rating, price, discount rate and etc.

Comment: @DHK https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you think you could add examples of how I would scrape, for example, 50 items and for 230 items?

Comment: @DHK do you really think that going from question to other one is useful for the community ? we are limited to provide an answer for the initial question. going from question to another is completely forbidden here!

Comment: Unaccepting contributor answer because he advised you to follow the rules is just confirming for us that our community is not for such users