# How to gets information from a website that contains Option

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to use what I have been studied to **scrape** information from a lotto website. The results are in 'option' selected for multiple draws, and i am facing the first difficulty that I can not 'get' any information that I need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'}

response = get('https://mylotto.co.nz/results')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

rs_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'draw-results lotto-draw-results')

print(rs_containers)
```

all I get is '[]' which I assuming it is None returns. Do I looking at wrong  ? or something else did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by _are in 'option' selected for multiple draws_, are you aware that the website is loaded via `JavaScript` where `requests` module will not help you to render it. use `selenium` or any other modules which can render the `JavaScript` for you.

Comment: thanks, for comment. I was engaging some website with JavaScript when I am practicing web scraping, that is why I choose this website and I did not see it has JavaScript, I must missed something. thanks for the tips, I will see what I can do with it.

Comment: I've already posted an answer for you @D1ag0

Comment: sorry I don't know how to type your name, but thanks very much for your solution, may I ask a question, is Json will solve the problem for such website loaded with Javascript? after ' .json() ' is that means i can ' request ' it by using python? thanks. @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-json-python-requests/

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, thanks very much , I have learned a lot today.

Answer (score 0):

Direct call to the `API`:

```
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    print(r['lotto']['lottoWinningNumbers'])
    print(r['powerBall']['powerballWinningNumber'])
    print(r['strike']['strikeWinningNumbers'])


main("https://apigw.mylotto.co.nz/api/results/v1/results/lotto")
```

Output:

```
{'numbers': ['06', '07', '09', '22', '24', '38'], 'bonusBalls': '39'}      
04
['38', '06', '07', '09']
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, may I ask where did you get 'https://apigw.mylotto.co.nz/api/results/v1/results/lotto' ? I just want to learn the way to deal with webpage loaded with JavaScript. Is it the way 'render from Javascript' by using selenium?

Comment: @D1ag0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989218/web-scraping-an-onclick-object-table-on-a-website-with-python/60990295#60990295